# How to use Google Play Referrer API to track referrer in Flutter App?

Tags: android, flutter, install-referrer

I'm trying to figure out how to access referrer info provided by Google Play Store using the [Play Install Referrer Library/API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library.html). Do I need to create a platform channel to the Android? And when should be the function be triggered?

Comment: I need that, too. I haven't found a Flutter library for the Play Install Referrer API yet, but implementing it using platform channels seems straight-forward.

Answer (score 7):

I have just implemented a Flutter plugin doing exactly that:

https://pub.dev/packages/android_play_install_referrer